# Passing an object as a parameter to a command

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I Have two commands in my eclipse plugin. (Upload and Run). They can be invoked by the user one after another. So it only makes sense to invoke Run after the upload command is done.

Since the upload command possibly takes some time it will schedule a WorkspaceJob for actual execution. And returns right after it scheduled the job.

What i like to do know is to add another command called "Upload and Run" which (suprisingly) is supposed to first upload and then run the selection. Therefore it must be notified when the `WorkspaceJob` started in the Upload command has finished.

So i'd like to parameterize the command with an additional `IJobChangeListener` which it will add when the `WorkspaceJob` is scheduled.

Unfortunately it seems to me like it's only possible to pass Strings as parameters to a command or Objects that can be converted to Strings easily. However a Listener like this cannot be passed as a String.

- How can i provide the command with such an Listener Object?
- Is there maybe an other way of providing the Listener Object to the Command (other than passing it as a prameter) that i didn't think of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your "Upload and Run" action is going to start the upload, you could then just schedule *another* job for the Run-action which simply calls `join()` on the workspace job-reference you have before doing anything else.

**Update:**
I think you're running into a limitation of the framework there. The commands are intended as an abstraction on the user-interface, not as an abstraction of getting things done. I'd simply go with reusing the Java code that you have, and directly invoke the code for both actions from the button for the joint functionality.

Comment: The Upload and Run method acutally just calls the "Upload" command which starts the workspace-job for upload so i can't access the workspacejov reference.